# creating typescript methods in a Angular 2 service

Tags: angular

I create several methods in typescript but now that I have moved them into Angular 2 it seem I cannot use them.

I even removed the work `function` but that did not work either. Here is the code below:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BooksService {

let books: Array<IBook> = [];
let idNumber = 0;


function ID(): number{
  return idNumber++;
}


function generateBooks(): void {

    createBooks("Programming for dummies","Drew j",Category.Programming, false);
    createBooks("Love story I won't read","Justin C",Category.Fiction, true);
    createBooks("Shooting for dummies","Autin Powers",Category.nonFiction, true);
    createBooks("Master Management","Dick Tracy",Category.nonFiction, false);
    createBooks("Advanced C++","Kevin j",Category.Programming, true);
    createBooks("How to eat pizza","Ted",Category.nonFiction, true);

}

function clearBooks():void{
   books = [];
}

function createBooks(name:string,author:string,category:Category,isAvailable:boolean): void{

    let newBook:IBook = {id:ID(),name:name,author:author,category:category,isAvailable:isAvailable};

    books.push(newBook);
}

function getAvailbleFictionBooks(books): string[] {

    clearBooks();
    generateBooks();

    let availableBooks: Array<string> = [];

    for(let currentBook of books){

        if(currentBook.isAvailable && currentBook.catergory === Category.Fiction){

            availableBooks.push(currentBook);
        }
    }

    return availableBooks;
}

function getAvailbleProgrammingBooks(books): string[]{

    clearBooks();
    generateBooks();

    let availableBooks: Array<string>=[];

    for(let currentBook of books){

        if(currentBook.isAvailable && currentBook.catergory === Category.Programming){
            availableBooks.push(currentBook);
        }
    }

    return availableBooks;
}

function getAvailbleNonFictionBooks(books): string[] {

    clearBooks();
    generateBooks();

    let availableBooks: Array<string>=[];

    for(let currentBook of books){

        if(currentBook.isAvailable && currentBook.catergory === Category.nonFiction){
            availableBooks.push(currentBook);
        }
    }

    return availableBooks;
}

function getAllBooks(): Array<IBook> {

    clearBooks();
    generateBooks();

    return books;
}

function checkoutBook(id:number): boolean {

  let bookCollection = getAllBooks;

  for(let book of bookCollection()){

    if(book.id === id && book.isAvailable){
      let index = books.indexOf(book);
      delete books[index];
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function checkInBook(book):void{
  books.push(book);
}

const allBooks = getAllBooks();

const availbleFictionBooks = allBooks.filter(book => getAvailbleNonFictionBooks(book));
const availbleProgrammingBooks = allBooks.filter(book => getAvailbleNonFictionBooks(book));
const availbleNonFictionBooks = allBooks.filter(book => getAvailbleNonFictionBooks(book));

for(let books of availbleFictionBooks){
    console.log(books);
}

}
```

I need the service to have those functions but there is obviously something I am missing.

Issue snapshot:

[image]

Comment: `this.` is something you need when calling these. Add it to the front where you call the functions. `this.createBooks("...` Same thing with `books` and other local variables.

Comment: Look R. Richards answer and I assume you also have injected the service where you need it?

Comment: I added this to `createBooks` and removed the `function` word but that did not work. Now I put it back when I hover over function it says `function expecting newline or ; `

Comment: @R.Richards please see commit and snapshot I added

Comment: You've so much wrong going on there. Wait, I'll try to give you answer @Drew1208.

Comment: @ASomeOneJ to the rescue! Well done, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the errors I immediately noticed and fixed.

First of all you can see the underline path in your import, that means that you don't have the correct path.

You were missing a bunch of this'es and some syntax errors. I have marked *some* of them as comments in the code. You REALLY should first of all start learning Angular 2. I suggest you check out [Angular](http://www.angular.io) And this is the tutorial on services: [Tour of heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) These tutorials are really helpful! :) There is things in your code that I might do differently, but everything you need to know is in the tutorials! :)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Category } from 'yourPath'; // add the correct path here!
import { IBook } from 'yourPath'; // add the correct path here!

@Injectable()
export class BooksService {

    books: Array<IBook> = [];
    idNumber = 0;


    ID(): number {
        return this.idNumber++; // this was missing!
    }

    generateBooks(): void { // this missing on all!
        this.createBooks("Programming for dummies", "Drew j", Category.Programming, false);
        this.createBooks("Love story I won't read", "Justin C", Category.Fiction, true);
        this.createBooks("Shooting for dummies", "Autin Powers", Category.nonFiction, true);
        this.createBooks("Master Management", "Dick Tracy", Category.nonFiction, false);
        this.createBooks("Advanced C++", "Kevin j", Category.Programming, true);
        this.createBooks("How to eat pizza", "Ted", Category.nonFiction, true);
    }

    clearBooks(): void {
        this.books = []; // this was missing!
    }

    createBooks(name: string, author: string, category: Category, isAvailable: boolean): void {
        let newBook: IBook = { id: this.ID(), name: name, author: author, category: category, isAvailable: isAvailable };
        this.books.push(newBook); // this was missing!
    }

    getAvailbleFictionBooks(books): string[] {
        this.clearBooks(); // this was missing!
        this.generateBooks(); // this was missing!

        let availableBooks: Array<string> = [];

        for (let currentBook of books) {
            if (currentBook.isAvailable && currentBook.catergory === Category.Fiction) {
                availableBooks.push(currentBook);
            }
        }
        return availableBooks;
    }

    getAvailbleProgrammingBooks(books): string[] {
        this.clearBooks(); // this was missing!
        this.generateBooks(); // this was missing!

        let availableBooks: Array<string> = [];
        for (let currentBook of books) {
            if (currentBook.isAvailable && currentBook.catergory === Category.Programming) {
                availableBooks.push(currentBook);
            }
        }
        return availableBooks;
    }

    getAvailbleNonFictionBooks(books): string[] {

        this.clearBooks(); // this was missing!
        this.generateBooks(); // this was missing!

        let availableBooks: Array<string> = [];

        for (let currentBook of books) {
            if (currentBook.isAvailable && currentBook.catergory === Category.nonFiction) {
                availableBooks.push(currentBook);
            }
        }
        return availableBooks;
    }

    getAllBooks(): Array<IBook> {
        this.clearBooks();
        this.generateBooks();
        return this.books;
    }

    checkoutBook(id: number): boolean {
        let bookCollection = this.getAllBooks(); //error here!!
        for (let book of bookCollection) { // You had an exta ( here
            if (book.id === id && book.isAvailable) {
                let index = this.books.indexOf(book);
                // delete books[index]; WRONG!
                this.books.splice(index, 1); // CORRECT
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    checkInBook(book): void {
        this.books.push(book);
    }
}
```